# Error while upgrading to MarkLogic 9.0-3

Tags: marklogic, glibc, marklogic-9

After uninstalling version 7, I am trying to run the command -

```
yum install /path/to/MarkLogic-rpm-file
```

but receiving following error -

```
Error: Package: MarkLogic-9.0-3.1.x86_64 (/MarkLogic-9.0-3.1.x86_64)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: MarkLogic-9.0-3.1.x86_64 (/MarkLogic-9.0-3.1.x86_64)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)
Error: Package: MarkLogic-9.0-3.1.x86_64 (/MarkLogic-9.0-3.1.x86_64)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit)
```

I have already run `yum install update` and `yum -y update glibc`. I'm running centos 64 bit virtual box. The one that is provided my MarkLogic University for grooming.

Comment: I gave a suggestion and stated that if that did not work, please provide more useful info such as OS. I am starting to think you are on an older version of centos or rhel like version six. Thus the error for glibc x64. So, what version of centos are you running?

Answer (score 1):

You do not give much information about OS - all helpful information...

But lets start with a basic sanity check: you are running this on a 64 bit machine, right? I ask this because glibc errors are predictable because of requirements, but I would expect an error on the 32 bit version.

If we have passed that step, then see below:

Please refer to this page:

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/installation/intro

You will see a table of notes per OS. You do not clarify CentOs or RHEL in your description, but they are both noted.

Among one of the requirements, you will see that the 32 bit version of glibc is required. For CentOS, for example, this is simple because they make  both 64 and 32 bit versions available. I suggest you try: `yum install glibc.i686`

If that does not get you over the hump, then please add a bit more details to your post related to OS, etc..

Comment: running yum install glibc.i686 command says Package glibc-2.12-1.209.el6_9.2.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Answer (score 0):

I typically run this yum command as part of my [mlvagrant scripts](https://github.com/grtjn/mlvagrant/blob/master/opt/vagrant/install-ml-centos.sh#L17) that automate MarkLogic deployment:

```
yum -y install glibc.i686 gdb.x86_64 redhat-lsb.x86_64 cyrus-sasl cyrus-sasl-lib cyrus-sasl-md5
```

Next to the link shared by David, you can also review OS requirements from here:

http://developer.marklogic.com/products/marklogic-server/requirements-9.0

HTH!